# Decompose theorems into parts

Tags: numbering, ntheorem

In the following code, the numbers of the theorem are 1 to 4. But I want to have the name wrote in the text : I want to decompose an hypothesis into many parts. I found some solution to have the two numerotation (number and letter) but I didn't find how to keep the number of the last theorem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothèse}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 1
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 2
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp} %I have to change the environment
    Hypothese 2 A
\end{hyp} %I have to change the environment

\begin{hyp} %I have to change the environment
    Hypothese 2B
\end{hyp} %I have to change the environment
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT
Here is the code of the first answer with a "new" problem : I have 4C 4D 4E instead of 4A 4B 4C

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothèse}


\newcounter{hyphelper}


\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 1
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 2
\end{hyp}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\edef\hypval{\the\c@hyp}
\renewcommand{\thehyphelper}{\hypval\Alph{hyphelper}}

\let\thehyp\thehyphelper
\let\c@hyp\c@hyphelper

\begin{hyp} 
    Hypothese 2 A
\end{hyp} 

\begin{hyp} 
    Hypothese 2B
\end{hyp} 
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 3
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 4
\end{hyp}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\edef\hypval{\the\c@hyp}
\renewcommand{\thehyphelper}{\hypval\Alph{hyphelper}}

\let\thehyp\thehyphelper
\let\c@hyp\c@hyphelper

\begin{hyp} 
    Hypothese 4 A
\end{hyp} 

\begin{hyp} 
    Hypothese 4B
\end{hyp} 
\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 4C
\end{hyp}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

---

Here is the code with the accepted answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothèse}
\newtheorem{hyp+}{Hypothèse}[hyp]
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname thehyp+\endcsname{\thehyp\Alph{hyp+}}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothèse 1
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothèse 2
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp+}
    Hypothèse 2A
\end{hyp+}

\begin{hyp+}
    Hypothèse 2B
\end{hyp+}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothèse 3
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothèse 4
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp+}
    Hypothese 4A
\end{hyp+}

\begin{hyp+}
    Hypothese 4B
\end{hyp+}

\begin{hyp+}
    Hypothese 4C
\end{hyp+}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document misses `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: Oups ^^ It's an example and I forgot it. But this code works on my computer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to define a new environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothèse}
\newtheorem{hyp+}{Hypothèse}[hyp]
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname thehyp+\endcsname{\thehyp\Alph{hyp+}}

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothèse 1
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothèse 2
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp+}
    Hypothèse 2A
\end{hyp+}

\begin{hyp+}
    Hypothèse 2B
\end{hyp+}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothèse 3
\end{hyp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a way without additional packages, by storing the `\c@hyp` counter value and using another counter to be stepped, `hyphelper`.

`\let\c@hyp\c@hyphelper` 'forces' LaTeX to step `hyphelper` instead of `hyp` and `\thehyphelper` is formated as `hypval\Alph{hyphelper}` -- all used within a group in order to prevent 'pollution' of later `hyp` environments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothèse}


\newcounter{hyphelper}


\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 1
\end{hyp}

\begin{hyp}
    Hypothese 2
\end{hyp}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\edef\hypval{\the\c@hyp}
\renewcommand{\thehyphelper}{\hypval\Alph{hyphelper}}

\let\thehyp\thehyphelper
\let\c@hyp\c@hyphelper

\begin{hyp} %I have to change the environment
    Hypothese 2 A
\end{hyp} %I have to change the environment

\begin{hyp} %I have to change the environment
    Hypothese 2B
\end{hyp} %I have to change the environment
\endgroup
\makeatother


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The screen shot is from a previous version where I omitted `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: What is the difference between with and without `inputenc` ?

With this solution, if I try to have another decomposed hypothesis the letter count continue with C D E instead of A B C (I edited the main post to give you the code I tested)

Comment: @Ccile: The difference is the missing `é` ;-) And the CDE is just because there is no resetting counter -- your question is not very clear regarding that, but you have made your decision already by unaccepting before providing the opportunity to react ...

Comment: Oups, there is an accent ^^ 
My question is not clear ? What is not clear ?

You can always react... I accepted the other solution because it works but if you have more arguments, please I want to know them